# Sails project - mysql connection 'Error: Consistency violation'

Tags: mysql, model, sails.js, sails-permissions

I have created a new sails project and installed sails-permission. First it worked fine. After creating connection to Mysql and did sails lift it throws an error as

```
error: Error: Consistency violation: A model (`passport`) references a
```

`datastore which cannot be found ('mysql').  If this model definition` `has an explicit` `connection` `property, check that it is spelled` `correctly.  If not, check your default` `connection` `(usually located in config/models.js).`

The Model passport.js is located in `node_modules/sails-permission/api/models`.

config/connections.js

```
 mysql: {
    module    : 'sails-mysql',
    host      : '127.0.0.1',
    port      :  3306,
    user      : 'review',
    password  : 'review',
    database  : 'reviews'
  },
```

config/models.js

```
module.exports.models = {
  connection: 'mysql',
  migrate: 'alter'
};
```

node_modules/sails-permission/api/models

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

function hashPassword (passport, next) {
  var config = sails.config.auth.bcrypt;
  var salt = config.salt || config.rounds;
  if (passport.password) {
    bcrypt.hash(passport.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
      if (err) {
        delete passport.password;
        sails.log.error(err);
        throw err;
      }
      passport.password = hash;
      next(null, passport);
    });
  }
  else {
    next(null, passport);
  }
}

  var Passport = {
  attributes: {

    password: { type: 'string', minLength: 8 },
    provider   : { type: 'alphanumericdashed' },
    identifier : { type: 'string' },
    tokens     : { type: 'json' },
    user: { model: 'User', required: true },

    validatePassword: function (password, next) {
      bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, next);
    }

  },
  beforeCreate: function (passport, next) {
    hashPassword(passport, next);
  },
  beforeUpdate: function (passport, next) {
    hashPassword(passport, next);
  }
};

module.exports = Passport;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It beacause of sails-mysql update. [https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mysql/pull/328/files].

Change `module` as `adapter` in

```
config/connection.js

mysql: {
    adapter    : 'sails-mysql',
    host      : '127.0.0.1',
    port      :  3306,
    user      : 'review',
    password  : 'review',
    database  : 'reviews'
  },
```